# How to avoid crash during stack buffer overflow exploit?

Tags: stack, memcpy, buffer-overflow, exploit

```
void deal_msg(unsigned char * buf, int len)
{
    unsigned char msg[1024];
    strcpy(msg,buf);
    //memcpy(msg, buf, len);
    puts(msg);
}

void main()
{
    // network operation
    sock = create_server(port);
    len = receive_data(sock, buf);
    deal_msg(buf, len);
}
```

As the pseudocode shows above, the compile environment is vc6 and running environment is windows xp sp3 en. No other protection mechanisms are applied, that is stack can be executed, no ASLR.

The send data is `'A' * 1024 + addr_of_jmp_esp + shellcode`.

My question is:

1. if `strcpy` is used, the shellcode is generated by msfvenom, `msfvenom -p windows/exec cmd=calc.exe -a x86 -b "\x00" -f python`,
   msfvenom attempts to encode payload with 1 iterations of x86/shikata_ga_nai
   after data is sent, no calc pops up, the exploit won't work.
   But if `memcpy` is used, shellcode generated by `msfvenom -p windows/exec cmd=calc.exe -a x86 -f python` without encoding works.
2. How to avoid the original program's crash after calc pops up, how to keep stack balance to avoid crash?

Answer (score 0):

1. Hard to say. I'd use a custom payload (just copy the `windows/exec cmd=calc.exe`) and put a `0xcc` at the start and debug it (or something that will be easily recognizable under the debugger like a `ud2` or `\0xeb\0xfe`). If your payload is executed, you'll see it. Bypass the added instruction (just NOP it) and try to see what can possibly go wrong with the remainder of the payload.
2. You'll need a custom payload ; Since you're on XP SP3 you don't need to do crazy things.

- Don't try to do the overflow and smash the whole stack (given your overflow it seems to be perfect, just enough overflow to control rIP).
- See how the target function (`deal_msg` in your example) behave under normal conditions. Note the stack address when the `ret` is executed (and if register need to have certain values, this depend on the caller).
- Try to replicate that in your shellcode: you'll most probably to adjust the stack pointer a bit at the end of your shellcode.
- Make sure the caller (`main`) stack hasn't been affected when executing the payload. This might happen, in this case reserve enough room on the stack (going to lower addresses), so the caller stack is far from the stack space needed by the payload and it doesn't get affected by the payload execution.
- Finally return to the ret of the target or directly after the call of the `deal_msg` function (or anywhere you see fit, e.g. returning directly to `ExitProcess()`, but this might be more interesting to return close to the previous "normal" execution path).
- All in all, returning somewhere after the payload execution is easy, just `push <addr>` and `ret` but you'll need to ensure that the stack is in good shape to continue execution and most of the registers are correctly set.